# Is there a R methodology to select the columns from a dataframe that are listed in a separate array

Tags: r, arrays, list, variables, select

I have a dataframe with over 100 columns. Post implementation of certain conditions, I need a subset of the dataframe with the columns that are listed in a separate array.
The array has 50 entries with 2 columns. The first column has the selected variable names and the second column has some associated values.
I wish to build a new data frame with just the variables mentioned in the the first column of the separate array. Could you please point me as to how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```html
library(dplyr)
iris <- iris %>% select(contains(dataframe_with_names$names))
```

Answer (score 0):

In R you can use square brackets `[rows, columns]` to select specific rows or specific columns. (Leaving either blank selects all).

If you had a vector of column names you wanted to keep called `important_columns` you could select only those columns  with:

```
myData[,important_columns]
```

In your case the vector of column names is actually a column in your array. So you select that column and use it as your vector:

```
myData[, array$names]
```